# elasticsearch - all terms in any fields

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

For a search function in an onlineshop, I'm using ongr's elasticsearchDSL ([git](https://github.com/ongr-io/ElasticsearchDSL) / [docs](http://docs.ongr.io/ElasticsearchDSL/index)).

Basic setup to search product names:

```
$boolQuery = new BoolQuery();
$boolQuery->addParameter('minimum_should_match', 1);
$wcQuery = new WildcardQuery('name', "*$_term*");
$boolQuery->add($wcQuery, BoolQuery::MUST);
```

This has an annoying behavior:

The query "notebook" finds all products with that term.
But the query "note book" finds nothing at all.

Maybe a wildcard query isn't the best practice anyways.

What I need:

- search multiple fields (name, description, manufacturer)
- no fuzzieness: find all the search terms in any of those fields

What's the best way to do that?

I've tried `MultiMatchQuery` with types `best_fields` and `phrase_prefix` and `SHOULD/MUST` combination, but either the result has too many irrelevant results or none at all.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html
here clearly mentioned that a wildcard term should not start with one of the wildcards * or ?.

Comment: thats true, but the server can handle that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out a solution:

```
$boolQuery = new BoolQuery();
$boolQuery->addParameter('minimum_should_match', '100%');

// search by manufacurer number
$wcQuery = new QueryStringQuery("$term", [
    'fields' => [ 'manufacturerNumber' ]
]);
$boolQuery->add($wcQuery, BoolQuery::SHOULD);

// split query into single terms
$term = explode(" ", trim(preg_replace("@[^a-z0-9äöüß\-]@", " ", strtolower($term))));

// find all terms in any fields
foreach($term as $_term){
    $wcQuery = new QueryStringQuery("*$_term*", [
        'fields' => [ 'name', 'shortDescription', 'manufacturerName' ]
    ]);
    $boolQuery->add($wcQuery, BoolQuery::SHOULD);
}
```

Leading wildcard isn't ideal I guess, but it works just fine like this. No performance issues at all.